# Change WLED Colorloop effect speed

Tags: c

I'm using [WLED](https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED) to control a Led-strip. I'm interested in the `Colorloop` effect. Using the web interface and setting the speed slider at minimum makes the loop effect going slow but not slow enough. 
I downloaded the `WLED` source code to change the function controls this effect:

```
/*
 * Cycles all LEDs at once through a rainbow.
 */
uint16_t WS2812FX::mode_rainbow(void) {
  uint16_t counter = (now * ((SEGMENT.speed >> 2) +2)) & 0xFFFF;
  counter = counter >> 8;

  if (SEGMENT.intensity < 128){
    fill(color_blend(color_wheel(counter),WHITE,128-SEGMENT.intensity));
  } else {
    fill(color_wheel(counter));
  }

  return FRAMETIME;
}
```

I'm not a `C` programmer and I cannot fully understand the `counter` calc. I tried this way but it doesn't seem to works!

```
uint16_t counter = (now * ((SEGMENT.speed >> 4) +2)) & 0xFFFF;
```

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume `now` variable is related to the `#include <time.h>` library, which if presented like this: `time_t now;` will return the current time of the system in number of seconds.

```
**>>** -  [variable]>>[number of places] denotes Bitwise Right Shift operator in C
```

As an example:

```
10 >> 1
0000 1010 >> 1  | Binary representation of 10
0000 0101       | we shifted 10 by 1 bit, the resulting binary is the number 5
Each Right Shift is a essentially dividing by 2.
```

See this video https://youtu.be/BKzB6gdRyIM?t=163

`&` Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.
EX: 101 &000 = 000, 110 & 101 = 100

`uint16_t` guaranteed to be a unsigned integer that is 16 bits large (up to 65535)

---

In your case:

```
uint16_t counter = (now * ((SEGMENT.speed >> 2) +2)) & 0xFFFF;
```

`((SEGMENT.speed >> 2) + 2)`
`SEGMENT.speed` is divide by 2 twice. SEGMENT.speed / 2 = **result1**, **result1** / 2 = **result2**.

**result2** is then  added by 2 = **result3**

**result3** is then multiplied by the value of `now`

`& 0xFFFF` is doing the AND operation of the bits between **result3** and **0xFFFF**

Let's say, **result3** = 200

200 in binary = 0000 0000 1100 1000

0000 0000 1100 1000

### 1111 1111 1111 1111

1100 1000 - 200